# Wrong configuration after master restart

Tags: activemq-artemis

We have a confiugration of 2 masters and 2 slaves, classic replication. The versions are artemis 2.28, java 11, running on windows. The cluster starts successfully. After killing one master, the corresponding slave becomes a master. After starting the killed server again we have a split bain problem. Both servers go live, each of them thinks its master.

The configuration for master is:

```xml
      <ha-policy>
         <replication>
            <master>
               <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
               <vote-on-replication-failure>true</vote-on-replication-failure>
            </master>
         </replication>
      </ha-policy>
```

And the configuration for slave is:

```xml
      <ha-policy>
         <replication>
            <slave><allow-failback>true</allow-failback></slave>
         </replication>
      </ha-policy>
```

Could you please advise what else we need to check?

Comment: Do you happen to clear the journal from the primary broker before you restart it?

Comment: No. Should we do it? Can you point to the documentation?

Comment: No. You definitely should not clear the journal before you restart the primary as that will certainly lead to this kind of behavior. I asked because folks do this sometimes without understanding the consequences. At this point you'll need to provide more details about how to reproduce the behavior you're seeing.